# MS access query with 2 or more delimter

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am trying to retrieve data from one column.
I tried to delimit using

```
Trim(Mid([RIC_Name],InStr([RIC_Name],"=")+1))
```

This works for only where "=" is available. I want to do similarly for "."

For example:

```
.abcdx.fx
werer=lu
jhgjj.nx
```

Output:

```
fx
lu
nx
```

Is this possible in one expression?

Comment: are you wanting to split it at every `.`?

Comment: What are you doing with this data once you've retrieved it? That is, is it necessary to attempt the splitting in the sql-statement?

Comment: I am trying to split and retrieve only last part of the cell. That is data which is after = or.(second . in some case). Once I get this data the I have to compare with other table using this column  and pull required fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the `InStrRev` function

```
Trim(Mid([RIC_Name],InStrRev([RIC_Name],".")+1))
```

you will get the answers shown in the question except for the second one which needs a different delimiter (=).

Depending on the use of this split, you can make the delimiter a variable and assign the appropriate delimiter to it. If you need one statement to crack both delimiters try something like this:

```
Trim(Mid[RIC_Name],iif(InStrRev([RIC_Name],".")+1<>0,InStrRev([RIC_Name],".")+1,InStrRev([RIC_Name],"=")+1)))
```

Comment: I tried using one statement but I get error" The expression you entered contains invalid syntax. you may have entered operand without an operator"

Comment: I changed your statement to    IIf(InStrRev([RIC_Name],"=")+1<>0,Trim(Mid([RIC_Name],InStr([RIC_Name],"=")+1)),Trim(Mid([RIC_Name],InStr([RIC_Name],".")+1)))                 but it works only for "="

Comment: Here is an example:
X = "a=abcd=xe":? Trim(Mid(X,iif(InStrRev(X,".")+1<>0,InStrRev(X,".")+1,InStrRev(X,"=")+1)))
This does ='s and .'s. .'s have priority the way I wrote it. It gets more complex if you want to do both delimiters with equal priority in only one statement.

Comment: Thanks Perry, this works.. I also used alternative by replacing all .'s to ='s and then my first statement in the question to split all the ='s.